# exporting with the same as import video presets

Tags: video, kdenlive

I have a 368mb of '.flv' video file. After editing I want to export the video with the same settings that I had imported it with (I had imported it with just drag and drop so I don't know explicitly all the presets) because when I choose from the render dialogue box a format that is provided I end up increasing the file size to about 1 GB. What are the ways that I do this in kdenlive so that I retain(or possibly minimize, I have only trimmed some unwanted aspects of the video) the video file size, frame rate, encoding, extension, dimension and all other aspects of the original video?

Answer (score 1):

It is not as such possible to automatically export with the same settings as the imported video because such settings are not stored with the produced video file. In addition, different encoders are in use, each that may have a different interface and present different settings. Therefore, you indeed will need to tune your export settings to match the desired quality of the output file and the desired size.

If you are just trimming unwanted content, then you probably should consider a linear video editor, allowing to remove sections without re-encoding. You can cut and join video without transcoding with ffmpeg (command line). Avidemux is a graphical program allowing to trim without transcoding.

Comment: Is there a way to manually set all the input to output setting? How do I read all the required input and how do I set all the required output?